# moving classification to production environment

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, pmml

I am designing the architecture of an analytics system . I have a classification ensemble model developed in scikit learn . I want to move this to the production environment so the new incoming data can be classified on the fly using this model. Ideally the system should support a manual upload of "model" into production system. I don't have any experience with analytics production systems.  Any suggestions would be very helpful

I have checked out Py2PMML But it does not support all the models. 
Primarily I am looking for Boosted tree regressions.
PS: I am not asking for code or samples. Just the right direction.

Comment: Why don vote ? its a legitimate question with right tags.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I guess it's because it's too broad question.

Comment: I understand. But i cant help it. I have done data modeling for over 5 years just dont know how to move it to production

Comment: Perhaps this will be more of use. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Essentially you are asking for an **off-site resource**, a library to run your model on the server...

Comment: @BhanuKaushik "But i cant help it" - If you can't help it, then definitely nor can we. This doesn't make it an on-topic question - it's all explained in the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there isn't an [official way](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1596) to export scikit models to PMML. The recommended way is to use pickle or `joblib.dump`. Please refer to the [model persistence](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) section of the docs. The idea is to save the model to disk with:

```
>>> from sklearn.externals import joblib
>>> joblib.dump(model, 'saved_model.pkl')
```

Then upload it to your server in production and load it with:

```
>>> model = joblib.load('saved_model.pkl')
```

It is important that you try to have similar environments, models saved in one version of scikit-learn might not load in another version.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its something I can work with. The help is appreciated @!!